# Determine which section is currently dispayed with react and Waypoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout, waypoint

I have quite simple react application:

App.js:

```js
render() {
 return (
   <BaseLayout />
 );
}
```

BaseLayout:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Section1 from "./section1/Section1";
import Section2 from "./section2/Section2";
import Section3 from "./section3/Section3";
import { Box, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import Fade from "react-awesome-reveal";
import { Waypoint } from 'react-waypoint';
```

where I simply display all sections at once and then show them with `Fade` animation. All is good. But I also want to highlight the current displayed section on the `Navbar` and change it accordingly during scrolling (currenlty highlighting happens only during clicking)

```js
  return (
    <Box className={darkMode ? Style.dark : Style.light}>
      <Grid
        container
        display={"flex"}
        flexDirection={"column"}
        minHeight={"100vh"}
        justifyContent={"space-between"}
      >
        <Grid item>
          <Navbar darkMode={darkMode} handleClick={handleToggleDarkMode} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item flexGrow={1} className={Style.firstContentRow}>
          <Section1 />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item flexGrow={1}>
          <Fade bottom triggerOnce={true} className={Style.secondContentRow}>
            <Section2 />
          </Fade>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item flexGrow={1} className={Style.firstContentRow}>
          <Fade bottom triggerOnce={true}>
            <Section3 />
          </Fade>
        </Grid>
        <Waypoint
          onEnter={({ previousPosition, currentPosition, event }) => {
            // PreviousPosition:below
            // CurrentPosition:inside
            // The above fields just return either `below` or `inside` and *NOT* for each section.
            console.log("PreviousPosition:" + previousPosition);
            console.log("CurrentPosition:" + currentPosition);

            // I see no usefull data here as well, did I miss something?
            console.log("Event:" + event);
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
```

for this I think I need to use `Waypoint` and some his event which should allow me to know which particular section is displayed now and then change a class name on a particular NavBar button accordingly. However, the information provided by waypoint event doesn't look enough. I can't find how can I understand which particular section is displayed at this point. Did I miss something? Also, the event is triggered not for each section, as I can see and only for the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To answer the question:

`<Waypoint/>` won't help to achieve what you want, it is not used for that, it is in fact a component that you can put inside your jsx.

> Works in all containers that can scroll, including the window.

when you scroll, you can think of it as a **point** that once reached, left, or changes position, the corresponding event is triggered.
the previous position when you enter this point is always "below" here, because you have put `<Waypoint/>` at the end of the grid.
the `event` object is not useful as well for what you want, if you check `event.doccument` you will find the whole scrollable element and not the last displayed element on the screen.

> event - the native scroll event that triggered the callback. May be missing if the callback wasn't triggered as the result of a scroll.

so it is usually used

> to build features like lazy loading content, infinite scroll, scrollspies, or docking elements to the viewport on scroll.

### Solution:

you can use three `<Waypoint/>` each one before each section and a state to indicate which is the last waypoint entred (the order of the section displayed):

```js
const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState(1);
```

then create a `useEffect` hook to run each time `currentSection` is updated:

```js
useEffect(() => { 
    console.log("current section is updated and this is its order ", currentSection);
    // now you have the number indicates of the current section you can manage how to make your nav bar react to that  
}, [currentSection]);
```

JSX:

```js
<Box>
  <Waypoint
    onEnter={() => {
      setCurrentSection(1);
    }}
  />
  <Grid
    container
    display={"flex"}
    flexDirection={"column"}
    minHeight={"100vh"}
    justifyContent={"space-between"}
  >
    <Grid
      item
      flexGrow={1}
      style={{ height: "800px", background: "red" }}
    >
      <div>section 1</div>
    </Grid>
    <Waypoint
      onEnter={() => {
        setCurrentSection(2);
      }}
    />
    <Grid
      item
      flexGrow={1}
      style={{ height: "800px", background: "white" }}
    >
      <div>section 2</div>
    </Grid>
    <Waypoint
      onEnter={() => {
        setCurrentSection(3);
      }}
    />
    <Grid
      item
      flexGrow={1}
      style={{ height: "800px", background: "green" }}
    >
      <div>section 3</div>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Box>
```

### Alternative (without waypoint):

I used to manage this with an event listener on scrolling and refs.

you want to give a `ref` and an `id` to each `grid` section container, also a state to indicate which section is currently on the screen:

```c
const firstRef = useRef();
const secondRef = useRef();
const ThirdRef = useRef();
const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState();
```

when the component mounts we `setCurrentSection` to the first section and set our event listener:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setCurrentSection(firstRef.current);

  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  };
}, []);
```

the `handleScroll` function will run each time you scroll and update the `currentSection` state, but likely this will rerender the component only when `currentSection` gets a new value :

```js
const handleScroll = () => {
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

  const sectionPositions = [
    firstRef.current,
    secondRef.current,
    ThirdRef.current
  ];

  const currentSection = sectionPositions.find(
    (section) =>
      scrollPosition >= section.offsetTop &&
      scrollPosition < section.offsetTop + windowHeight
  );

  if (currentSection) {
    setCurrentSection(currentSection);
  }
};
```

finally, we create a `useEffect` hook that will be triggered each time the value of `currentSection` is updated:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentSection) {
    console.log("current section is updated and this is the id of the current one: ", currentSection.id);
    // now you have the id of the current section you can manage how to make your nav bar react to that
  }
}, [currentSection]);
```

### Full example:

```js
const Test = () => {
  const firstRef = useRef();
  const secondRef = useRef();
  const ThirdRef = useRef();

  const [currentSection, setCurrentSection] = useState();

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollPosition = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const sectionPositions = [ firstRef.current, secondRef.current, ThirdRef.current ];
    const currentSection = sectionPositions.find(
      (section) =>
        scrollPosition >= section.offsetTop && scrollPosition < section.offsetTop + windowHeight
    );

    if (currentSection) {
      setCurrentSection(currentSection);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentSection(firstRef.current);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentSection) {
      console.log("current section is updated and this is the id of the current one: ", currentSection.id );
      // now you have the id of the current section you can manage how to make your nav bar react to that
    }
  }, [currentSection]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Box>
        <Grid
          container
          display={"flex"}
          flexDirection={"column"}
          minHeight={"100vh"}
          justifyContent={"space-between"}
        >
          <Grid
            id={1}
            item
            flexGrow={1}
            style={{ height: "800px", background: "red" }}
            ref={firstRef}
          >
            <div>section 1</div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            id={2}
            item
            flexGrow={1}
            style={{ height: "800px", background: "white" }}
            ref={secondRef}
          >
            <div>section 2</div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            id={3}
            item
            flexGrow={1}
            style={{ height: "800px", background: "green" }}
            ref={ThirdRef}
          >
            <div>section 3</div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: the first approach perfectly works, second one throws `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetTop')` during scrolling.

Comment: however at this point I'm ok with the first one too

Comment: @Unnamed both approaches are working fine for me, the only explanation of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetTop')` is that the scroll event handler is fired before useEffect finishes ,weird!, but you still can wrap the code inside `handleScroll` within this condition `if(firstRef.current && secondRef.current && thirdRef.current)` and it should work

Comment: the second approach works for me now too!